# Socket Programming (Client - Server UDP)

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I would like to build a client - server model where, for any number of clients connected to the server, the server should send a broadcast Message. Below is the code which I implemented, it does not throw any error, but I could not see any communication happening between the server and the client. Please let me know, where is the problem in the code.

I would like to see the message passed from the server on the clients system.

```
    /************* UDP SERVER CODE *******************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int udpSocket, nBytes, buflen;
  char buffer[1024];
  char string[1024];
  int portNum;
  struct sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;
  struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
  socklen_t addr_size, client_addr_size;
  int i;

  /*Create UDP socket*/
  udpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  portNum=atoi(argv[1]);
  /*Configure settings in address struct*/
  serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serverAddr.sin_port = htons(5000);
  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.117");

  memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);  

  /*Bind socket with address struct*/
  int bStatus=bind(udpSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
   if (bStatus < 0) {
        printf("error binding on server's port number\n"); 
        exit(1);
  }     


  /*Initialize size variable to be used later on*/
  addr_size = sizeof serverStorage;

memset(&clientAddr, 0, sizeof(clientAddr));
  clientAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  clientAddr.sin_port = htons(portNum);  // this is where client is bound
  clientAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.114");

  while(1){
sprintf(buffer,"Hello Client");
  buflen=strlen(buffer);
  int bytesSent = sendto(udpSocket,buffer,buflen,0,(struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr, sizeof(clientAddr));
  if (bytesSent < 0) {
        printf("Error sending/ communicating with client\n");
        exit(1);
  }
  printf("%s\n",buffer);

/*
// ****************************************************

memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
buflen=65536;
recvfrom(udpSocket,buffer,buflen,0,(struct sockaddr *)&serverStorage, &addr_size);
printf("Received from server: %s\n",buffer);  

*/
}

  return 0;
}
```

Below is the client code :

```
     /************* UDP CLIENT CODE *******************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int clientSocket, portNum, nBytes, buflen;
  char buffer[1024];
  char string[1024];
  struct sockaddr_in serverAddr,clientAddr;
  socklen_t addr_size;

  /*Create UDP socket*/
  clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
 portNum = atoi(argv[1]);
  /*Configure settings in address struct*/
  serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serverAddr.sin_port = htons(portNum);
  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.117");

//  memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);  
memset(&serverAddr,0,sizeof(serverAddr));


// binding 
bind(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, sizeof(clientAddr));


  /*Initialize size variable to be used later on*/
  addr_size = sizeof serverAddr;

  while(1){

memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
buflen=65536;
recvfrom(clientSocket,buffer,buflen,0,(struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, &addr_size);
//recvfrom(clientSocket,buffer,buflen,0,NULL,NULL);
printf("Received from server: %s\n",buffer);

/*
//********************************************************************

sprintf(buffer,"Hello Client");    
 buflen=strlen(buffer);
 sendto(clientSocket,buffer,buflen,0,(struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr,addr_size);
 printf("%s\n",buffer);
*/
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you `bind`on the receiving end?

Comment: "*UDP*", "*connected*", hmmm?

Comment: @KevinDTimm isn't this valid c++ code?

Comment: @KamiKaze - there is nothing in this code that suggests usage of any part of c++.

Comment: why is your receive buffer 1024 bytes but the `length` parameter is 65535?

Comment: *it does not throw any error*  Of course not.  It's C code - it won't *throw* anything.  **You** have to check for errors - which you're not doing.

Comment: @KevinDTimm The absence of c++ unique code doesn't make it c. And as he requested c++ the possible solution might differ.

Comment: @KamiKaze - in which case he should not have included the `c` tag

Comment: And `printf("Received from server: %s\n",buffer);`?  Why do you assume the data you receive is a NUL-terminated string?  You don't *send* a NUL-terminated string.

Comment: This `192.168.1.117` is (one of) your server's local interfaces, right?

Comment: Why do you pass the address of an uninitialised `serverStorage` to `sendto()` as target?

Comment: @alk it _is_ possible to call `connect()` on a UDP socket, but mostly all that does is create local state, it's not truly "connected" in the way that a TCP socket is.

Answer (score 1):

At a high level there are a few things that need to be addressed. Given the code in the post has a server that initiates communication with the client following line needs to be modified (and related code for these)

On the server side:

```
  sendto(udpSocket,buffer,buflen,0,(struct sockaddr *)&serverStorage,addr_size);
```

Essentially what's happening here is that udpSocket is bound to serverAddr and  we are trying to sendto serverStorage (2nd last argument). The trouble here is that the serverStorage is not bound to anything. Basically sendto has the source right but not the destination.

On the client side:

```
recvfrom(clientSocket,buffer,buflen,0,(struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, &addr_size);
```

The clientSocket is not bound to anything so the system picks a random port where it will listen. In the recvfrom call, 2nd last argument captures the address details of the other side. Whereas in the code you have bound it to server's IP and port, it does not have any effect because it is filled in by the recvfrom call and returned.

To make things work here is what I'd suggest (you can add the details but have worked out the skeleton based on what you posted)

server_initiating_with_client.c

```
    //...
    int udpSocket, nBytes, buflen;
    char buffer[1024];
    int portNum;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;
    struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
    socklen_t addr_size, client_addr_size;

    /*Create UDP socket*/
    udpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    portNum=atoi(argv[1]);
    /*Configure settings in address struct*/
    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(5000);   // Making sure server has a unique port number
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    /*Bind socket with address struct*/
    int bStatus = bind(udpSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    if (bStatus < 0) {
        printf("error binding on server's port number\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*Initialize size variable to be used later on*/
    addr_size = sizeof serverStorage;

    /* Because server is initiating the communication here one needs to set the
     * clientAddr and needs to know the port number of the client
     */
    memset(&clientAddr, 0, sizeof(clientAddr));
    clientAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientAddr.sin_port = htons(portNum);
    clientAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    while(1){
        sprintf(buffer,"Hello Client");   
        buflen=strlen(buffer);
        int bytesSent = sendto(udpSocket,buffer,buflen, 0,
            (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr, 
            sizeof(clientAddr));
        if (bytesSent < 0) {
            printf("Error sending/ communicating with client\n");
            exit(1);
        }
            printf("Done sending %s\n", buffer);
                sleep(1);
    }
    ..
```

and on the client side something along these lines

```
    //..
    int clientSocket, portNum, nBytes, buflen;
    char buffer[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddr;
    socklen_t addr_size;

    /*Create UDP socket*/
    clientSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    portNum = atoi(argv[1]);
    /*Configure settings in address struct*/
    memset(&clientAddr, 0, sizeof(clientAddr));
    clientAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientAddr.sin_port = htons(portNum);
    clientAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));


    /*Bind on client side as well because you are specifically sending something over
    * to the client. Usually the server will know where to talk back to the client
    * but in your example because of the reversed semantics this will be needed
    */

    bind(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, sizeof(clientAddr));

    /*Initialize size variable to be used later on*/
    addr_size = sizeof serverAddr;

    while(1){
        memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
        buflen=65536;
        recvfrom(clientSocket,buffer,buflen,0,(struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, &addr_size);
        printf("Received from server: %s\n",buffer);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
```

The code can be simplified if you reverse your comm from client to server, thereby, eliminating the need for a fixed port number on the client side.

Comment: Thanks, @Aniruddh, for the explanation and for the code. Based on your guidelines, I have modified the code and updated in the code section. The confusing aspect is that it still not communicating.

Comment: Updated bit more to give you more clues. Run the program with a port number other than 5000 which is there on the server side for binding. But I'd suggest you to re-think this from client communicating with server. Clients typically will be many and it does not make sense for the server to know apriori port number of clients. Essentially I'd recommend starting from sending to server on a well known port but on the client side not binding on anything. The server should then read from the recvfrom and communicate back on the same address. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

just make a few changes in it. Assign a socket length predefined (socklen_t *) structure to typecast length

```
n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE,MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,  (socklen_t*)&len);
```

socklen_t* convert a length into socket length.
Make these changes at both  client-side as well as a server-side
.

---

Comment: He doesn't even have a `len` variable, and he is presently using `addr_siz` for that parameter, which is already a `socklen_t`, so he doesn't have this problem in the first place.